# Tipos de pagamento proibidos no IOS

Tags: ios, pagamento-online

Que tipos de pagamentos são exatamente proibidos no IOS, ouvi dizer que todos devem utilizar o in-app purchase... No meu caso quero liberar uma versão gratuita com funcionalidades limitadas para o usuário e caso ele goste, ele compra a versão completa usando cartão crédito, quero adicionar ainda a possibilidade de o usuário comprar itens que serão entregues na casa dele, algo como, camisetas, garrafas de água etc.
Para esses casos sou obrigado a utilizar o in-app purchase? Ou posso receber os dados do cartão e processar em um gateway de pagamento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a seção ***11.2*** da [**App Store Review Guidelines for iOS**](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)(*Login necessário - você também pode ler [**aqui**](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2010/09/apples-app-store-review-guidelines-annotated-explained)*) qualquer aplicativo que não utilize o *In-App* será rejeitado.

> Aplicativos que utilizam um sistema diferente do *In App Purchase*(*IAP*) para a compra de conteúdo, funcionalidade ou serviços em um aplicativo serão rejeitadas.

Além disso, note que qualquer compra de bens ou serviços do mundo real não é permitido de acordo com a seção ***11.3***.

> Apps usando *IAP* para compra de bens físicos ou bens e serviços utilizados fora do aplicativo será rejeitada.

Porém de acordo com essa resposta no [**SOEn**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5992718/1608936) é possível utilizar serviços de terceiros.

> Por exemplo, o [**PayPal Express Checkout**](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/) para dispositivos móveis funciona desse modo.

Comment: Excelente! antes de marcar como a resposta, saberia de me dizer como funciona o do aplicativo da decolar.com, porque ele pede os dados do cartão do usuário, e se ele utiliza algum gateway de pagamento não fica transparente?!?

Answer (score 6):

O resumo é simples:

- Você deve usar `In App Purchase (IAP)` para compras de bens virtuais, tais como funcionalidades extras ou itens e fases especiais em jogos.
- Você deve utilizar um sistema de pagamento diferente para comprar bens reais, tais como camisas, tickets para shows, pagamento de estacionamentos e afins que são muito comuns em aplicativos da `AppStore`.

Para implementar o segundo tipo de compra, você precisa utilizar um `gateway` de alguma empresa de pagamentos digitais como o [PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/) ou o [Pagar.me](https://pagar.me/).