# Alternativas para pagamentos de bens ou serviços com cartão de crédito no iOS

Tags: ios, pagamento-online

Gostaria de implementar um meio de pagamento no iOS para venda de **produtos/serviços do mundo real**, assim como funciona em aplicativos de `e-commerce`.

> Como visto em [Tipos de pagamento proibidos no IOS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13538/tipos-de-pagamento-proibidos-no-ios) é possível realizar esse tipo de transação já que se trata de bens e serviço do mundo real.

Procurando soluções que façam esse tipo de transação, fui atrás do *SDK do PayPal*, mas acabei descobrindo que não é possível fazer transações diretas (sem conta no PayPal) com cartão de crédito do Brasil.

Gostaria de saber que outras empresas fazem esse tipo de serviço no Brasil, de preferência que tenham um SDK para o iOS e que não precise acessar uma página web para realizar a transação.